# Php Mysql Database Query coding

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetching data from database. I want that on each day my id starts from 1, auto incremented after inserting each record but reset to zero after end of the day. Start same from the next day. But I am not able to find proper solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate more by showing some code snippet and what your expected outcome?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes then add the code you have tried.

Comment: That sounds like you didn't think this through.
Typically, you'd want your id in a table to be unique.
ask yourself : Why do you need a different set of Id's per day, and is there any way i could infer a daily unique id *without* compromising my table structure?

Comment: i am referring it by id but in real my id ll be unique. take another field 'appointment_no.' i want that on each day appointment start from 1 and till end of day get auto incremented on each inserted record. But start from 1 again on next day.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways to ["reset" the auto-increment value](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/reseting-mysql-autoincrement-column/).

If the auto-increment column is the identifier, then the simplest approach would probably be to simply truncate the table:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
```

This would of course **delete all of the data**, but since you're deleting identifiers then the data isn't really meaningful anymore anyway.  (And if that's *not* the case then you're going to want to give this entire endeavor some more thought, because re-using identifiers is a famously bad idea.)

If, on the other hand, the auto-increment is *not* the identifier and duplicates are allowed, then manually resetting the value should work:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

As for doing either of these each day, simply set up a daily `cron` job to run at midnight.  Or, failing that, if you are restricted only to a request/response web application then when writing to the table you can first check if the last written record was or was not on the same day as the current day.  If it wasn't, reset the auto-increment.  (It's not the most performant approach, but in the absence of background tasks it gets the job done.)